# including "winmain.h" vs <windows.h>

Tags: c++, windows, include, header-files

I'm using MSVC 2015, and I tried to compile (`cl`) some code containing `#include "winmain.h"`. It failed with `fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'winmain.h': No such file or directory`. However, when I changed the include to `#include <windows.h>`, it compiled fine.

Searching for information online, I find numerous places where these files are included, but I find no mention of when `winmain.h` would be unavailable and should be replaced with `<windows.h>`.

When should I use one or the other, and when on what platforms are each of them (un)available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`winmain.h` is not a standard Windows or MSVC header. Code using the Win32 API needs to include the `windows header` a.k.a. `windows.h`. See for example [Using the Windows Headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745.aspx).

Comment: Is it perhaps a MinGW thing?

Comment: @NateGlenn I don't know, and you didn't mention where your `#include "winmain.h"` came from. It could be just a local file from whatever project you copy/pasted from. One thing to notice is that `#include "winmain.h"` uses `""` quotes, which indicate a local/user file, while `#include <winmain.h>` uses `<>` angle brackets which indicate a standard/system header.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Everywhere I search online I seem to see custom included local winmain.h files, so this makes sense. The context is [CRF++](https://github.com/taku910/crfpp/blob/master/crf_learn.cpp), which I couldn't compile until switching out the winmain.h includes.

Comment: P.S. Too late to edit my previous comment now, but obviously the second `#include <winmain.h>` was meant to read `#include <windows.h>`.